# Sync Document Libraries

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, document-library

How can a document library in On-Premises SharePoint 2013 but kept in sync with a document library in SharePoint Online automatically?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to push data into SharePoint online is via either CSOM or REST APIs. Either way, it's a client side tech. Since your source is on prem, you can use event receivers (DocumentUpdated) as the trigger which would push the update via the client side tools to 365. 
Start with event receivers here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx
Start with CSOM here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx
If you prefer REST, start here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx

Comment: Ya i agree!!!!!!

Comment: So if a document is added to the document library on either on-prem or in SharePoint Online it will get synced?  For example, if an external part who has access to SharePoint Online uploads a document to a SharePoint Online document library it would get synced to on-prem document library (and vice-versa)

Comment: Since you cannot deploy event receivers to 365, you'll need some kind of job that checks the online content to pull updates.